# Processing game: Gif images not respawning as intended

Tags: java, processing, game-physics

I am a diploma student making a game based on processing, it's a tower defense game where a heroine would be shooting arrows at zombies charging towards the castle. I have multiple issues with this.

1. The charger zombies do not respawn after being shot dead.
2. All of the charger zombies die together when I shot only one charger zombie.

Supposedly I wanted the zombies to spawn in waves repeatedly after a group of them has been shot down, and then I want the charger zombies to die individually, depending on the one I click on.

Here's my source code:

```
import processing.opengl.*; // transparency
import gifAnimation.*; // after add gifAnimation library
import ddf.minim.*; // importing music

PImage backgroundImg;
PImage animation;

int counter;

//settings
int score = 50, totalScore = 0;
int titleX = 200, titleY = 200;
boolean shotsFired = false;
PFont scorePoints, castleHealthPoints, font; //font for startingScreen
int chargerKilled;

//Charger class
int maxChargerOnScreen;
Charger[] chargerArr;   //chargerArray undefined
int chargerIndex;
final int numCharger = 300;
ArrayList<Charger> onScreen = new ArrayList<Charger>();

boolean chargerReachedTarget = false, chargerShot = false, chargerDive = true;
Gif chargerCharge, chargerAttack, chargerDied, shootingStance;
int chargerMoveX = 800, chargerMoveY = 450;


// CastleWallHealth
int castleHealth = 1000;

// audio 
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;
AudioSnippet arrowShoot;

//-------------------------------Codes start here --------------------------------------------------// 
void setup() {
    //ipad mini size
    //  frameRate(10);
    frameRate(60);
    size(800, 600);
    smooth();

    minim = new Minim(this);
    // song = minim.loadFile("InGameSoundtrack.mp3");
    // song.play();
    arrowShoot = minim.loadSnippet("arrowSound1.wav");

    backgroundImg = loadImage("GameBackground.jpg"); 
    backgroundImg.resize(800, 600);
    chargerCharge = new Gif(this, "ChargerCharge.gif");
    chargerAttack = new Gif(this, "ChargerAttack.gif");
    chargerDied   = new Gif(this, "ChargerDie.gif");
    gargoyleFly   = new Gif(this, "GargoyleFly.gif");
    gargoyleAttack = new Gif(this, "GargoyleAttack.gif");
    shootingStance = new Gif(this, "ShootingGif.gif");

    scorePoints =  createFont("Arial", 16, true);
    castleHealthPoints = createFont("Arial", 16, true);
    // loopingGif.play() plays the animation without loop
    // must make charger
    chargerCharge.play();
    chargerAttack.play();
    chargerDied.play();

    resetGames();  // starts with respawning 5 charges 
}

void draw() {
    // backgroud
    background(backgroundImg);
    image(shootingStance, 120,200);

    // scores and health
    textFont(scorePoints, 15);
    fill(0);
    text("Score: " + totalScore, 100, 100);
    displayCastleHealth();

  //*********************************************charger settings code********************************************************************
    // If there's no more zombies. prompt reset (screen no zombies) , index from 0 add till 300 then game won
    if (onScreen.size() == 0 && chargerIndex == numCharger) {
        println("Game won! :)");
        // gameWon = true;
    }

    // while onScreen charger less than 5 only and chargerIndex havent reach 300 it will only respawn 
    while (onScreen.size () < maxChargerOnScreen && chargerIndex <= numCharger - 1) {

        if (chargerIndex < chargerArr.length) { // <--- this is the problem chargerArrayLength
            Charger chargerMobs = chargerArr[chargerIndex];
            // starts from chargerArray[0] to chargerArray[300]
            onScreen.add(chargerMobs);                         
            chargerIndex++;
            // chargerIndex keeps looping why?
            // println("ADDED ZOMBIE TO ONSCREEN Zombs on screen: " + onScreen.size());
        }
    }

    // Adjusts maxZombOnScreen based off the current index   Difficulties?
    if (chargerIndex == 10)
        maxChargerOnScreen++;
    else if (chargerIndex == 50)
        maxChargerOnScreen++;
    else if (chargerIndex == 100)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 2;
    else if (chargerIndex == 150)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 2;
    else if (chargerIndex == 190)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
    else if (chargerIndex == 250)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
    else if (chargerIndex == 260)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
    else if (chargerIndex == 270)
        maxChargerOnScreen += 5;

    // removes dead zombies, living zombies act normally
    for(int i = 0; i < onScreen.size(); i++) {
        Charger c = onScreen.get(i);

        // add money when a zombie is dead
        // if (c.getHealth() <= 0)
        if (chargerShot==true) {
            c.chargerDying();
            onScreen.remove(i);
            chargerKilled++;
            i--;
        } else {
            c.act(); ///it should just act
        //  c.displayHealth(); // if gt time only do
    //  }
        }
    }

    // creating list of predetermined zombies and their characteristics
    println("chargerIndex: " + chargerIndex); // debug
    println("onScreenSize: " + onScreen.size());
//  println("ChargerArray: " + chargerArray.length); chargerArray point null?

    // cursor
    if (mouseY > height - 500) {
        noFill();
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 35, 35);
        line(mouseX - 25, mouseY, mouseX + 25, mouseY);
        line(mouseX, mouseY - 25, mouseX, mouseY + 25);
    }

}

void resetGames() {
    // resetting variables
    chargerIndex = 0;
    maxChargerOnScreen = 5;
    chargerKilled = 0;
    createNewCharger();
}

void createNewCharger() {

    Charger[] temp = new Charger[numCharger];
    for (int i = 0; i < numCharger; i++)    
        temp[i] = new Charger((int) random(800, 1200), chargerMoveY);

    chargerArr = temp;
}

//____________________________________________________________________________________________________________-
class Charger {

    private int chargerMoveX, chargerMoveY;
    Gif chargerGif; // by default
    // chargerGif will change based on input (either it reaches the castle or its shot)

    // no constructor
    Charger() {
        chargerMoveX = 0;
        chargerMoveY = 450; 
    }

    // overloaded constructor
    Charger(int cMoveX,int cMoveY) {
        chargerMoveX = cMoveX;
        chargerMoveY = cMoveY;
    }

    void act() { // use 

        // if reached castle it wont move
        if (chargerMoveX <= 180) {
            // remove gif images
            chargerDive = false;
            chargerReachedTarget = true;
        }

        // if not shot or reached castle it will move 
        if (chargerDive == true) {
            chargerGif = chargerCharge;
            image(chargerGif, chargerMoveX, chargerMoveY);
            chargerMoveX -= 2;
        }

        // if reached castle perform attack animation
        if (chargerReachedTarget == true) {
            chargerGif = chargerAttack;
            image(chargerGif, chargerMoveX - 80, chargerMoveY - 120);
        }

        if (mousePressed &&
            mouseX < chargerMoveX + 180
            && mouseX > chargerMoveX
            && mouseY < chargerMoveY + 120
            && mouseY > chargerMoveY) {

            // score board     
            totalScore = totalScore + score ;      
            float r = random(50);
            println(r);
            chargerShot = true;
            chargerDive = false;
        }

    }

    void chargerDying() {
        chargerReachedTarget = false;
        chargerGif = chargerDied;
        image(chargerGif, chargerMoveX, chargerMoveY);
    }
}

void displayCastleHealth() {
    if (castleHealth <= 0) {
      fill(250, 70, 0);
      textFont(castleHealthPoints, 20);
      text("HP: 0", 100, 50);
    } else {
      fill(250, 70, 0);
      textFont(castleHealthPoints, 20);
      text("HP: " + castleHealth, 100, 50);
    }
}

void mousePressed() {
    strokeWeight(2);  
    arrowShoot.rewind();
    arrowShoot.play(); 

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
        shootingStance.play();

    shotsFired = true;
}

void mouseReleased() {
    strokeWeight(1);

    if (shotsFired == true)
        shootingStance.pause();
}

public void stop() {
    arrowShoot.close();
}
```

Majority of the problems from the charger came from here:

```
if (onScreen.size() == 0 && chargerIndex == numCharger) {
    println("Game won! :)");
    // gameWon = true;
}

// while onScreen charger less than 5 only and chargerIndex havent reach 300 it will only respawn 
while (onScreen.size () < maxChargerOnScreen && chargerIndex <= numCharger - 1) {

    if (chargerIndex < chargerArr.length) { // <--- this is the problem chargerArrayLength
        Charger chargerMobs = chargerArr[chargerIndex];
        // starts from chargerArray[0] to chargerArray[300]
        onScreen.add(chargerMobs);                         
        chargerIndex++;
        // chargerIndex keeps looping why?
        // println("ADDED ZOMBIE TO ONSCREEN Zombs on screen: " + onScreen.size());
    }
}

// Adjusts maxZombOnScreen based off the current index   Difficulties?
if (chargerIndex == 10)
    maxChargerOnScreen++;
else if (chargerIndex == 50)
    maxChargerOnScreen++;
else if (chargerIndex == 100)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 2;
else if (chargerIndex == 150)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 2;
else if (chargerIndex == 190)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
else if (chargerIndex == 250)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
else if (chargerIndex == 260)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 3;
else if (chargerIndex == 270)
    maxChargerOnScreen += 5;

// removes dead zombies, living zombies act normally
for(int i = 0; i < onScreen.size(); i++) {
    Charger c = onScreen.get(i);

    // add money when a zombie is dead
    // if (c.getHealth() <= 0)
    if (chargerShot==true) {
        c.chargerDying();
        onScreen.remove(i);
        chargerKilled++;
        i--;
    } else {
        c.act(); ///it should just act
    //  c.displayHealth(); // if gt time only do
//  }
    }
}
```

Evaluation and criticism is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry! I have forgotten! Its Java based.

Comment: @Unihedron Did you really try this with http://processing.org/ ? (I'm not sure whether this *needs* to be in a class, I'm just asking ... )

Comment: @Marco13 Sorry, I was too tired and tried a Java compiler instead.

Comment: @Unihedron No problem. In fact, it's usually rather easy to convert a processing script into a Java class (usually just wrapping it into a class that extends `PApplet`, IIRC). Maybe I can try to do this in the next few days, because otherwise, I guess the question might remain unanswered (the number of processing users is tiny compared to the number of Java users...)

Comment: @Marco13 Favourited and bookmarked. Eagerly looking towards your solution!

Comment: @Unihedron I did not *promise* anything ;-) Let's see whether someone answers, and if not, I'll have another look at this during next week...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with the code, but for now, I'll ignore the parts that are somewhat "not clean" or "not elegant", and focus on the main problem that was the reason for the question:

The *state* of all `Charger`s instances was the same. The fields

```
boolean chargerReachedTarget = false, chargerShot = false, chargerDive = true;
```

have been defined globally. Just by moving this line (that is, these 3 fields) into the `Charger` class, and changing the line

```
if (chargerShot==true) {
```

to

```
if (c.chargerShot==true) {
```

the game already seemed to be much closer to what you presumably have been looking for. After this modification, it was possible to shoot *individual* opponents, and new opponents kept coming after the old ones had disappeared.

Again: The code is not really nicely structured, and there are many possible minor improvements. For example, something like `if (c.chargerShot==true) { ... }` should better be `if (charger.isShot()) { ... }`. But I'm not so familiar with *processing* and its best practices, so I'm not sure how the "best" solution would look like in a global sense...